# FullCalendar not initializing on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use FullCalendar, but it's not initializing, before i have pushed today, week ore the day button. I have tried to set det defaultView parameter, but makes no different's.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function () {


        /* initialize the external events
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

        $('#external-events div.external-event').each(function () {

            // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
            // it doesn't need to have a start or end
            var eventObject = {
                title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
            };

            // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
            $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

            // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
            $(this).draggable({
                zIndex: 999,
                revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
            });

        });


        /* initialize the calendar
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay',
                height: 650
            },
            editable: true,
            defaultView: 'basicWeek',
            droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
            drop: function (date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

                // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
                var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

                // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
                var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

                // assign it the date that was reported
                copiedEventObject.start = date;
                copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

                // render the event on the calendar
                // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

                // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                    // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                    $(this).remove();
                }

            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

The calendar is inside an  [jquery ui tab](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#default)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an solution. After initializing the calendar i call this function

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    show: function (event, ui) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
    }
});
```